# XML file cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I have made a xml file for my android application(**FileChooserExampleActivity.xml**), and register it in **Andriodmanifest.xml** file, but when i am going to call it in **FileChooserExampleActivity.java**. Eclipse doesn't recognize it as an interface

The error is:

**Multiple markers at this line
    - FileChooserExampleActivity cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field**

Is there any thing wrong with Androidmanifest.xml?

Manifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ipaulpro.afilechooserexample"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".FileChooserExampleActivity"   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

FileChooserExampleActivity class is:

```
public class FileChooserExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.FileChooserExampleActivity);
         }
```

Comment: FileChooserExampleActivity.xml 
should be in lower case also as they said in the answers below it should be (R.layout.filechooserexampleactivity); not R.id...

Answer (score 0):

Name convention wants the  res/layout files start with a lowerCase letter. So you should rename `FileChooserExampleActivity.xml` to `fileChooserExampleActivity.xml`

```
setContentView(R.id.FileChooserExampleActivity);
```

probably you want to have

```
setContentView(R.layout.fileChooserExampleActivity);
```

and you have to create an xml file inside res/layout named `fileChooserExampleActivity.xml`

Answer (score 0):

change `setContentView(R.id.FileChooserExampleActivity);` to `setContentView(R.layout.FileChooserExampleActivity);` and then try.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the content view to R.layout.your_file and it still didn't work try looking for errors in your XML file else just clean your project. I just fixed a similar issue by simply cleaning my project.
Good luck!